# How to get a value from a nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting below sample json data as input,

```
var JSONDATA =
    {
        "MainNode": {
            "_attributes": { 
                "class": "ABC",
                "projectclass": "MyProject",
                "prjname": "PrjName",
                "enabled":"true"
            },
            "PrjProp": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "name": "MyProject.save" 
                },
                "_text": true 
            }
        }
    }
```

Using Jquery or Javascript, I want to get the `"projectclass"` value in first "_attributes". There could be multiple `"_attributes"` in JSON object but the requirement to the `"projectclass"` (fixed) from the first (fixed) `"_attributes"` only.

This can be achieved like,
console.log(JSONDATA.MainNode._attributes.testclass);

but `"MainNode"` is not fixed, this can be `"OtherNode"`. So how to handle this is variable ? I tried , `console.log(Object.keys($scope.testplan)[0]);` which shows main node name but how to use this in  `console.log(JSONDATA.MainNode._attributes.testclass);`  as variable ?

Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to access as `JSONDATA.MyProject._attributes.projectclass`

Using `[0]` is accessing the first element of an array. This is an object, so that is the reason why you are not able to access `JSONDATA[0][0].projectclass`

```js
var JSONDATA = {"MyProject":{"_attributes":{"class":"ABC","projectclass":"MyProject","prjname":"PrjName","enabled":"true"},"PrjProp":{"_attributes":{"name":"MyProject.save"},"_text":true}}};

console.log( JSONDATA.MyProject._attributes.projectclass );
```

And there is going to be only 1 `_attributes` under `MyProject`.

---

If you have multiple *projects*, You can loop by:

```js
var JSONDATA = {
    "MyProject":{"_attributes":{"class":"ABC","projectclass":"MyProject","prjname":"PrjName","enabled":"true"},"PrjProp":{"_attributes":{"name":"MyProject.save"},"_text":true}},
    "MyOtherProject":{"_attributes":{"class":"ABC","projectclass":"MyOtherProject","prjname":"PrjName","enabled":"true"},"PrjProp":{"_attributes":{"name":"MyProject.save"},"_text":true}}
};
 
for ( var key in JSONDATA ) {
    console.log( JSONDATA[key]._attributes.projectclass );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `JSONDATA[0][0]` to acces a JSON object
for example `data` is your JSON object to access `projectclass` simply

```
  data={
    "MyProject": {
        "_attributes": {
            "class": "ABC",
            "projectclass": "MyProject",
            "prjname": "PrjName",
            "enabled": "true"
        },
        "PrjProp": {
            "_attributes": {
                "name": "MyProject.save"
            },
            "_text": true
        }
    }
}
console.log(data.MyProject._attributes.projectclass);
```

Comment: It Works. But i missed to mention one thing that main node ""MyProject"" may change in inputs. So we can not hard code to "data.MyProject._attributes.projectclass" because it may be "data.OtherProject._attributes.projectclass" and there will be one project only. I apologize for incomplete information.